# are there any methods to implement page transitions when using <a href>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i made some several html files. at the main page i just wrote down some codes like this

```
  <a href="new.html>
    <img src="img/button" id="buttonid">     
  </a>
```

when i click the button, i see that the web starts new.html activity. I want to put some smooth page transitions when i open that "new.html".  I searched through internet, and found out that most of the page transitions are done by putting other class into  format.  Whatever, are there any methods for page transitions that can be implemented when using  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hijack your `<a>` tag and handle its behaviour through javascript.

***FadeOut part***

Start with giving it an empty target :

```
 <a href="#"> ... </a>
```

So when you click it, nothing happens.
Then, use a custom attribute to store the URL you want to load when clicking this tag :

```
<a href="#" data-url="new.html"> ... </a>
```

Then add some class that will allow javascript / jQuery to target your link :

```
<a href="#" data-url="new.html" class="smoothLink"> ... </a>
```

In your javascript, target your smoothLinks and write a delayed action (using jQuery here) :

```
$("a.smoothLink").click( function(e){
    $("body").fadeOut(function(){ // This will fade out your entire page in about half a second. When it's done, execute the callback function
             window.location = e.currentTarget.attributes['data-url'].value;
     });
}
```

However, for performance reasons, I strongly advise you to prefer CSS3 opacity animations (opacity 1 --> 0 --> 1) because, unlike jQuery's fade functions, they're hardware accelerated.

Here's how to do :

(JS)

```
 $("a.smoothLink").click( function(e){
        $("body").addClass("fadeOut"); // anything with the "fadeOut" class will become transparent in 1s in our CSS

        setTimeout( function(){ // wait 1s, then change URL
            window.location = e.currentTarget.attributes['data-url'].value;
        }, 1000)
 }
```

(CSS)

```
.fadeOut {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

**FadeIn part**

Once your new page is loaded, it has to be blank, then fade in. Start with making the whole body transparent :

(CSS)

```
body{
    opacity :0;
}
```

Then, fade it in.

*Using the jQuery method :*

```
$("body").fadeIn()
```

*Using the CSS3 method :*

In your HTML, give the body a "fadeIn" class :

(HTML)

```
<body class="fadeIn">
```

Back to your CSS, write an instruction for fading in anything with the "fadeIn" class :

(CSS)

```
.fadeIn {
     opacity: 1;
     transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

So, on page load, your body will gradually get visible in 1 second.
I have to say this in untested, but should be a nice hint :)

**EDIT - **
**Simpler solution with a white overlay**

Just cover your whole page with a full white overlay, that you can make transparent or opaque at will :

(HTML)

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

(CSS)

```
div#overlay{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:white;
    pointer-events:none; // so you can click through

    opacity : 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

(JS)

```
$("div#overlay").css("opacity",0); // will fade out the overlay on page load

$("a.smoothLink").click( function(e){
                $("div#overlay").css("opacity",1);

                setTimeout( function(){ // wait 1s, then change URL
                    window.location = e.currentTarget.attributes['data-url'].value;
                }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
         $('a.smoothLink').click( function(e){
            $("body").addClass("fadeOut"); // anything with the "fadeOut" class will become transparent in 1s in our CSS

             setTimeout( function(){ // wait 1s, then change URL
                window.location = e.currentTarget.attributes['data-url'].value;
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>

Comment: ithe console says that $ is undefined??

Comment: Yeah, $ stands for jQuery. It means you are not using it and you need to include this library. http://jquery.com/

Comment: the fadeout part works! i fixed my javascript. however

Comment: how can i make my background image also fade out??
i wrote

Comment: background: url(...)
into the css part
at html{   ... }

also the fadein doesnot work T_T

Comment: i fixed the fadein part. it also works
thank you very much
however do you have any idea how to handle the background img?

Comment: Man, if you have a background image to your body, it gets harder. I had a new, much simpler idea : cover your whole page with a full white overlay. I have edited my answer.

Comment: GOD like.
thanks for answering to my silly questions. 
Hope you have a nice day~!

Comment: Hehe, no worries. We've all been through this :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make some transition is to use ajax as Jquery Mobile does in example (have a look at http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to sort of spoof it, I use Jquery for ease of use here.
in your css set the body tag to display none then with jquery on document load set it to fade in, I've done it at 3 seconds for effect and done an alert etc. muck around with it..

```js
$( "body" ).fadeIn( 3000, function() {
    alert('Billys spoofed slow sort of fade in');
 $('body').css('color','red');
  });
```

```css
body{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello from fade in</h1>
```